# How to implement logical constraints in cplexAPI for R

Tags: r, cplex

I went through the Quick Start guide January 30, 2017 and noticed there was no mention of logical constraints.

Is this a limitation of the API package or is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you refer to rcplex api? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/Rcplex.pdf

An easy way to do that is to use OPL and R through https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/blog/2018/10/26/use-opl-r-framework/

Comment: I was referring to [this package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cplexAPI/index.html)

Comment: Then you could rely on addIndConstrCPLEX Adds an Indicator Constraint to the Specified CPLEX Problem Object

Comment: hmm there it is.  I guess I'm blind.